# Where can I sell WordPress themes and plugins?

Tags: plugins, themes

I've been building some WordPress themes and plugins. What are the online marketplaces I can sell them?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

here is a nice brake down for you:

### MarketPlaces

**Themes:**

***[Theme Forest](http://themeforest.net/)***
 - Probably the biggest theme marketplace by Evanto. [Rates: New authors begin at the 50%](http://themeforest.net/wiki/selling/getting-paid/payment-rates/).

***[Templamatic](http://www.templamatic.com/)***
 - [Rates: between 50% and 70%](http://www.templamatic.com/faq.asp).

***[BuyStockDesign](http://www.buystockdesign.com/)***
 - [Rates: Start from 50% to 75%](http://www.buystockdesign.com/MakeMoney.html#3).

***[BuySellWordpress](http://www.buysellwp.com/)*** 
 - [Rates: Starts from 50% and may go up to 70%](http://www.buysellwp.com/sell/).

***[WPmart](http://www.wpmart.net/)***
 - Free listing.

**Plugins:**

***[Code Canyon](http://codecanyon.net/)***
 - Probably the biggest Plugin marketplace again by Evanto.
 - [Rates: New authors begin at the 50%](http://codecanyon.net/wiki/selling/getting-paid/payment-rates/)

***[WPPlugins](http://wpplugins.com/)***
 - The only other major plugin market place by Incsub.
 - Rates: 70% fixed.

***[WPmart](http://www.wpmart.net/)***

### Forums

There is a lot of potential for selling templates on webmaster and webdev forums with marketplaces and very high traffic:

- [Webmaster-Talk](http://tycoontalk.freelancer.com/marketplace/)
- [TalkFreelance](http://www.talkfreelance.com/forumdisplay.php?f=59)
- [Digital Point](http://forums.digitalpoint.com/forumdisplay.php?f=24)

### Other Designers and Developers

Two approaches here

- Contact Designers and Developers who are selling in there own sites and ask to list your theme/plugin for a cut of the profit (negotiate well).
- Contact Designers, Developers and Website builders look for there portfolios and see if you have a product (theme/plugin) they would need and use, offer to license a such product so they could use for there customers.

and lastly,

### Sell on your Own site

Its harder then any other option but you get to keep 100% of the profits so if you market your self the right way you won't need any of the places listed here :)

Answer (score 7):

Envato has [Theme Forest](http://themeforest.net/) and [Code Canyon](http://codecanyon.net/). I don't know how the GPL lovin' WordPress community feels about it, but my company has bought things from there when we needed to. They aren't updateable from the wp-admin though, so...

Comment: As far as I know, Envato requires WordPress Themes/Plugins to comply with GPL - not in the "100% GPL-as-on-WPORG" sense, but in the "PHP-files-inherit-GPL" sense.

Answer (score 3):

Though not nearly as large, [WP Plugins](http://wpplugins.com/) is another marketplace for plugins.

Code Canyon and Theme Forest are by far the largest though.

Comment: wpplugins.com is current best address for premium plugins

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to make free versions of your plugins / themes which you submit to Wordpress plugins / themes directory, and include in them links to your paid versions. Is the best way to promote your work.

Here http://mashable.com/2009/02/28/sell-designs-online/ you can find an extended list of marketplaces.

I would also recommend [Mojo Themes](http://www.mojo-themes.com/)

Answer (score 1):

There's been a massive discussion about selling Premium themes but at the end of the day you own the copy right to all code/images which don't call on WordPress functions.

Also look at [Mojo Themes](http://www.mojo-themes.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Then what is the situation of plugins?

Comment: @Alex Older: The end of the day is if you either create a derivate or not. Normally with Plugins and Themes you do. But that's not a problem as long as you stay compatible to the GPL. @Jeff: Same for Plugins.

Comment: If it's not using a WP function, how can it be a theme? Unless you're grabbing all the global vars and building out your template by iterating over that. Hmm. Sounds like a fun project :)

Comment: "Dependent" != "derivative". The legal definition of a derivative work requires *actual incorporation of copyrightable code*. But, it's probably best not to get into GPL-inheritance arguments here at WPSE. :)

Answer (score 1):

you have your own website means try with this one:[Your Own Store](http://wpmu.org/sell-your-own-wordpress-themes-with-marketpress-and-gridmarket/).Create your own store & get 100% profit.otherwise theme forest & Mojo themes are good.:)

UPDATE:

while i googling i found top 20+ websites for you.[Great Collection of websites](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/wordpress/theme-marketplaces/).it'll very very helpful to decrease your googling time :)

Comment: About the 1stwebdesigner.com link: We are talking about where one can sell and not buy!

Comment: @:ashfame- Read the title fully{20+ Best Marketplaces Where You Can Buy And **Sell** High Quality WordPress Themes}

Comment: I think you need to read the title of the question and not what you are quoting, Period.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an AppStore-like marketplace: http://www.plugpress.com/